# Hibernate do not persist data on the database (see update 3)

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, sessionfactory

In my current Spring project, I have this Hibernate configuration on my `rootCOntext.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">  

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql:mydata"/>
        <property name="username" value="klebermo"/>
        <property name="password" value="123"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.kleber.model" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

but when the application needs to execute this query:

```
@Transactional
public List<E> select(String orderby, String groupby) {
    return (List<E>) this.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(clazz).setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
}
```

which is contained on this class:

```
public abstract class Dao<E> {
    protected Class<E> clazz;

    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Dao(Class<E> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public Session getCurrentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
    ...
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:134)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:456)
    org.kleber.model.Dao.getCurrentSession(Dao.java:22)
    org.kleber.model.Dao.select(Dao.java:43)
    org.kleber.model.Service.select(Service.java:35)
    org.kleber.model.Controller.list(Controller.java:87)
    org.kleber.model.Controller$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$aa38cb3a.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:652)
    org.kleber.model.usuario.UsuarioController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7dce8c33.list(<generated>)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
```

Anyone can see what's wrong here?

**UPDATE**

I change my DAO method for this:

```
@Transactional
public List<E> select(String orderby, String groupby) {
    Session sess = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    List<E> list = null;
    try {
        tx = sess.beginTransaction();
        list = sess.createCriteria(clazz).setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if(tx != null)
            tx.rollback();
        throw e;
    } finally {
        sess.close();
    }
    return list;
    //return (List<E>) this.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(clazz).setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
}
```

and now I am getting this error:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: org.kleber.model.usuario.Usuario.listas, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:582)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:201)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:145)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:261)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:102)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:119)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:79)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:18)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:292)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3681)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3057)
    org.kleber.model.Controller.list(Controller.java:88)
    org.kleber.model.Controller$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$aa38cb3a.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:652)
    org.kleber.model.usuario.UsuarioController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7c57ca50.list(<generated>)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
```

Which I guess points to the issue of how I implement the relationships between my class from Model layer.

that's my class:

```
public class Usuario {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Column
@Input
@Text
private String login;

@Column
@Input
@Password
private String senha;

@Column
@Input
@Text
private String nome;

@Column
@Input
@Text
private String sobrenome;

@Column
@Input
@Email
private String email;

@OneToOne
private Cart cesta;

@ManyToMany
private List<Wishlist> listas;

@ManyToMany
private List<Orders> pedidos;

@ManyToMany
@Select
private List<Credencial> credenciais;

@Column
@Input
@Date
private java.util.Date expirationDate;

@Column
@Input
@Checkbox
private Boolean locked;

@Column
@Input
@Checkbox
private Boolean enabled;
}
```

Someone knows how to solve this? Without use `FetchType.EAGER` for the `ManyToMany` relationships (If I do that, the application doesn't even start, because I get an error hibernate can't fetch multiple bags).

**UPDATE 2**

I try this in my DAO method:

```
@Transactional
public List<E> select(String orderby, String groupby) {
    Session sess = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    List<E> list = null;
    try {
        tx = sess.beginTransaction();

        Criteria criteria = this.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(clazz);
        if(orderby != null)
            criteria = criteria.addOrder( Order.asc(orderby) );
        if(groupby != null)
            //TODO
        for(Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if(field.isAnnotationPresent(ManyToMany.class))
                criteria = criteria.setFetchMode(field.getName(), FetchMode.EAGER);
        }
        list = criteria.list();

        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if(tx != null)
            tx.rollback();
        throw e;
    } finally {
        sess.close();
    }
    return list;
}
```

and now I a getting the first error mentioned in this post.

**UPDATE 3**

So, I manage to fix this error changing the method `getCurrentSession()` Dao class to that:

```
public Session getCurrentSession() {
    return sessionFactory.openSession();
}
```

but now when I submit data from my forms, they are not persisted on the database, despite no error being triggered.

Comment: Hello. I'd like to help you with this problem. Is it required to use xml-based configurations?

Comment: yes, it's what I am using for this current project.

Comment: And also is it required to used Criteria API. I mean is that possible to use HQL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code. Let's start from the beginning.

`@Transactional` is not working in your case. This is clearly visible from your stacktrace which you copied because Spring uses proxy objects to implement transactional calls. As I see, your configuration should be OK, so the only thing I can think of is that you are using wrong annotation.

Unfortunately there are 2 `@Transactional` annotations, one from the javax.transaction package and one from org.springframework.transaction.annotation package. Obviously, you have to use the latter one, otherwise it won't work properly.

Second thing, lazy initialization exception. This is happening because you are trying to initialize a lazy relation outside of a transaction.

There are multiple solutions for this:

1. Fetch it inside a transaction
2. Fetch it directly with the original query

The first thing will solve the issue, however it will not perform really well compared to the second solution.

For the first thing, you can do this by calling any method on the lazy collection, for example

```
list.getLazyCollection().size()
```

or you can use Hibernate's mechanism to do this:

```
Hibernate.initialize(list.getLazyCollection())
```

The only important thing is to do this inside a transaction.

The latter solution, which is fetching the relation directly involves either JPQL/HQL queries or Criteria API in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I use the same packages as you and i have those two additional entries in my `xml` config file:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypkg.daos"/>
<context:annotation-config/>
```

As you are using `@Transactional` and `@Autowried` annotations then i guess it would be a good idea to add those two config attributes.

Comment: But i had this two entries, in my `applicationContext.xml` file, referenced in my `web.xml` with the `init-param` tag associated to the servlet entry for `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`. Do I need duplicate them on my `rootContext.xml` file too?

Comment: Yes i have them duplicated so you can give it a shot

Comment: ok, i did that, but don't solve the issue (same error occurs).

Comment: the select(..) method.. is that in a class marked with @Repository or @SErvice?

Comment: it's in a generic class. the derived class is marked with @Repository.

Comment: is the problem only during that query.. or general?

Comment: In this stage of project it's hard to tell. Only security layer implemented, retrieving login data from database (which I guess don't use hibernate). Hibernate also import some initial data from `import.sql` file, but I also guess it's a different method to do that.

Comment: isnt the  org.kleber.model.Service class marked as transactional by any chance?

Comment: I tried both ways: with and without the annotation. None of them work.

Comment: The only difference that i see is the dataSource class type. Im using : org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource

Answer (score 0):

I guess that spring is not able in injecting the `SessionFactory` correctly

I would enable spring annotation transactions in your XML; try to give a look here  http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html; you should enable transaction or by adding in your configuration class this `@EnableTransactionManagement` or by adding in your XML this: `<tx:annotation-driven/>`

Then what I'd do is the following:

I'd write this repository DAO

```
   @Repository
     public class Dao<E> {
        protected Class<E> clazz;

        @Autowired
        protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        public Dao(Class<E> clazz) {
            this.clazz = clazz;
        }

        public Session getCurrentSession() {
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }
        public List<E> select(String orderby, String groupby) 
        {
         return (List<E>) this.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(clazz).setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
        }
    }
```

Then i'd create a service class where I'd do the following

```
@Service
public class ServiceClass<E>
{
  @Autowired
  private Dao<E> repos;

@Transactional
public List<E> select(String orderby, String groupby) {
    return repos.select(orderby, groupby);
}
}
```

I hope this is usefull

Angelo

Comment: Transaction is already enabled on my project, via `<tx:annotation-driven/>` in my XML configuration, and I have the `@Transactional` annotation both on methods from my Dao and Service class. Still don't working.

Comment: @KleberMota don't put transaction on DAO but only in service

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try set the data source on your **transactionManager** instead of **sessionFactory**, like this:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Reason for this change can be found on this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/HibernateTransactionManager.html#setSessionFactory-org.hibernate.SessionFactory-).
Also, ensure that you have the following:

1. `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>` declared on your `xml` file, in your case in `rootContext.xml.`
2. `<context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject"/>` to make beans visible to Spring.
3. `@Repository` on your DAO.
4. `@Transactional` on your method(s) or at class level.

   3. and 4. lets Spring apply and create proxies with Transaction support.

Comment: transactionManager is not working only with the property `dataSource` (the application even do not start). If I try with both `dataSource` and `sessionFactory`, the same error occurs. In regards with the other options, all of them are already in place.